# URL of docker hub image for usage in azure service fabric

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, dockerhub

I have created docker hub repo and also created and pushed a docker image of python application to the repo.

However, I cannot find the correct Url of the image that I have to provide to the other services which will use this image. for eg azure service fabric or Kubernetes.

How can I find the exact URL?  Through PowerShell or through the browser...

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually download images by url. Instead, you use the docker CLI with the repository and image name.

- If it's a private repo, login first, by using `docker login` 
  [more about login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/)
- Use `docker pull {reponame/imagename:tag}` to download an image to your machine.
  [more about pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub)
- Replace {reponame} with the [repository name](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/).
- Replace {imagename} with the name you used with `docker push`.
- Replace {tag} with the tag you put on the image (or `latest`).

For example, I use this line to get my docker hub image:
`docker pull loekd/nanoserver:2.0`